# Bresenham's Line Algorithm

Tags: algorithms

This is a page from the book [Schaum's Outline of Computer Graphics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071357815).

[image]

The text says, Selecting T means $d_i>=0$, and, selecting S means $d_i<0$.

I didn't understand why.

Can you please explain?

Comment: For something easier to read see page $6$ [here](http://info.lnpu.edu.cn/website/jpkc/jsjtxx/zxkt/Chapter%203%20Scan%20Conversion.pdf).

Comment: It is important to remember that the Bresenham algorithm concerns only vectors with slope betwen $0$ and $1$ (lower 'half first quadrant' so that the only possible next pixels are at the right or diagonal). When the slope is between $1$ and $+\infty\;$ you'll simply have to revert $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ (for the vector $v:=(\Delta x,\Delta y)$). For the other quadrants you may consider the absolute value for $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ and change the $x$ and/or $y$ increment from $+1$ to $-1$ at each step of the pixels generation.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni, what would be the starting value of $d_i$?

Comment: The starting value should be $\;d = 2\,(y'_2-y'_1)-(x'_2-x'_1)$ (see my updated answer). Of course this concerns only the first quadrant **and** $dx\ge dy$. For the other quadrants x++ and y++ should become x-- and/or y-- and for $|dx|<|dy|\;$ x and y should be exchanged. Note too that all the values are integers (the vector is $(x'_1,y'_1)\to (x'_2,y'_2)$ and not the initial one!).  Hoping this clarified things!

Answer (score 0):

Well at iteration $i$ we select (c.f. the first paragraph) :

- $T$ if $s\ge t$ (upper choice : the smallest/nearest $t$ is chosen) and
- $S$ if $s< t$ (lower choice : the smallest/nearest $s$ is preferred)

Since $d_i=\Delta x(s-t)$ has the same sign as $s-t$ ($\Delta x>0$)...

---

### Bresenham algorithm

I'll suppose that $x'=[x], y'=[y]$ with $[x]$ the nearest integer ('round' function) and $\,0\le y'_2-y'_1\le x'_2-x'_1=dx,\;dx>0\;$ for the vector $(x'_1,y'_1)\to (x'_2,y'_2)$
then, from your reference, the algorithm should (I didn't try it!) be :

```
int x = round(x1), y = round(y1); 
int xM = round(x2), yM = round(y2); 
int dx = xM - x, dy = yM - y, dT = 2*(dy - dx), dS = 2*dy; 
int d = 2*dy - dx; 
setPixel(x, y); 
while (x < xM) 
{ 
  x++; 
  if (d < 0) 
     d = d + dS; 
  else 
  { 
     y++; 
     d = d + dT; 
  } 
  setPixel(x, y); 
}
```